# Evaluation of given definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate the definite integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi /2} \cot \bigg(\frac{x}{2} \bigg) (1-\cos ^4x).dx$$

Could something give me hint as how to proceed in this question? I tried factorising  $(1-\cos ^4x)$ and using $1-\cos ^2x=\sin^ 2x$ but the expression does not simplify.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: show that your integrand is given by $$\sin \left( x \right)  \left( 1+\cos \left( x \right)  \right) 
 \left(  \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}+1 \right) 
$$